# Facebook application (Static HTML)

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a landing page on facebook with the Static HTML application, but the image does not appear in IE8 show only at 9 and other browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

The application link is: https://www.facebook.com/hyundainic/app_128953167177144.

Yet another application that looks like:
https://www.facebook.com/SomosEskimo/app_367456286664440.

This if displayed in all browsers, except that technically I do not know if it's the same.

I'm editing the html / css and occupy absolute and relative positioning, I thought that this could affect and remove it, but the problem persists forever.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is probably that you are using an absolute, non-SSL URL for the image source, and the links you posted to the app use SSL. If you leave the protocol off (example: "//whatever.com/myimage.jpg" instead of "http://whatever" or "https://whatever") the browser will use https when needed.

However, it looks like your image doesn't work over SSL:

```
https://hyundai.com.ni/img/quickservice-fb.jpg?id=3
```

You can try viewing your app using http:// and confirm it displays ok in all targeted browsers to see if this is really your issue.